# Does Django admin provide group edit of models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

For instance, I have a model called Person, and it has a bool field called 'isAthlete'. I would like to be able to check off True for 50 of these Person records, and then hit submit, without having to go into each Person model record and make the change. Is there an easy or already provided way to set this up in Django?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this using django admin actions, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/